# Is there a way to switch Git remotes without carrying Commit history?

Tags: git

I've recently set up a local Gitea instance for storing code to and easily continuing on another machine or device on my network, But when I'm ready to put the code on GitHub I don't want to carry all the unneeded commits from unfinished work with it.

Comment: Remote repositories are copies of local repositories, so if you want to change history in remote, first, you need to do it locally. I think you should search about commit squash. It is a way to group multiple commits in a single one.

Comment: If unfinished work means branches you no longer intend to merge, you could try to set up an empty remote repository and push only your main branch there, then clone that remote repo all over and take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

In Git, history is commits; the commits are the history.  If you don't like the history you have—i.e., the commits you have—make different commits.  That's all there is to it.

A Git *repository* is simply a collection of commits, as found by branch and tag names.  When you use `git push`, you're sending commits from your repository to another repository.  They receive the commits, and then you ask them to set one or more of *their* branch and/or tag names to find the commits you have sent them.  Send them the commits you'd *like* to see in their repository, then ask them to set the desired branch name.

If you have commits that you sort-of-like and sort-of-dislike, you'll probably want to *copy* those commits to new-and-improved commits.  The command for copying a single commit is `git cherry-pick`.  It normally works by copying the effect of the commit and making a new commit on whatever branch you're on now, so to build a new branch with improved commits, you:

- create the new branch, pointing to the last *good* commit;
- use `git cherry-pick`, perhaps with `-n` to prevent it from making a *new* commit right now, giving it the hash ID of the commit you want to copy.

For large collections of commits—e.g., if you need to copy and improve a dozen or so commits—this is a bit painful, so you'll want to use the Git command that *automates* this process.  That command is `git rebase`.  In its *interactive* mode, it makes rearranging and combining commits relatively easy.  Note that it's much harder to *split* a commit into several commits, so it's usually good planning to make many small commits, which you can easily group together however you like, rather than to make a few big commits that you have to split.

Note that `git rebase` works by:

- listing out the commits to copy;
- checking out, as a *detached HEAD*, some particular commit where you want the copies to go;
- repeatedly doing `git cherry-pick`, perhaps with some squash and/or fixup operations and the like as directed by your interactive rebase (if you choose an interactive rebase); and finally
- *moving* some branch name to remember the last-copied commit.

This depends on the fact that we (humans) don't find commits by hash ID, the way Git does; we find them by *branch names*, usually.  Git stores *one* commit hash ID in each branch name.  The hash ID that Git has stored in this branch name *is* the *last commit in the branch* (by definition).

There are more tools than *just* interactive rebase.  It's just that interactive rebase is sort of the usual go-to tool, the way people working on building a home mostly carry around hammers and saws and screwdrivers.  You'll still need an occasional table saw, or jig for door hinges, or orbital sander or whatever, but *most* of the time you'll use a small set of power tools.  You want to get good at all of these tools.  This takes time and practice, so take some time and practice.